# Finder favourites bar disappeared in "open/save file" dialog box

Tags: mac, finder, macos

when I try to save or open file in e.g. Pages app the "Favourites" side bar does not show up, as shown on the image:

[image]

However it's there when using Finder:

[image].

Comment: What version of Pages & OS X is that? - mine looks different on Pages 5.6 & OS 10.10.5